# Vertical scroll bar and fixed headers with mat-table

Tags: css, angular-material, angular-material-table

I would like to know how to display a vertical scroll bar for the rows only (headers are not moving) with Angular Material mat-table. When I set `overflow: auto` and `max-height` in `mat-table` style, the whole table (including the headers) are scrolled.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You may use the sticky property of [MatHeaderRowDef](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatHeaderRowDef):

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
```

Comment: @corleone88 glad it helps. If it solved the problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: Note that fixing the table.mat-table height or max-height didnt work for me, had to fix the parent container to a fixed height, and that trick works!